# Can I wrap the text in a VisualForce dataTable and cause the row to line

Tags: visualforce, datatable

I am using apex:dataTable in a VisualForce page in order to display two columns with three rows. The second column is a 'Comments'column.

So, the datatable is as such :

```
    <apex:dataTable value="{!Review__c}"  id="ventable" var="pitem" border="4" align="left" cellpadding="10" rowClasses="rowWithBorder"> 

                <apex:column headerValue="First Column">                                
                      <apex:outputLabel >ARow-FirstColumn  </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                      <apex:outputLabel >BRow_FirstColumn   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                      <apex:outputLabel >CRow_FirstColumn   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Comments Column">                                
                       <apex:outputLabel >ARow_CommentsColumn  </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                       <apex:outputLabel >BRow_CommentsColumn   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                       <apex:outputLabel >CRow_CommentsColumn   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

I would like for my Comments column's text to wrap - AND I would like for the first column's field to keep in line with Comments as it wraps. As it is now the First column's fields do not get pushed down as the Comments wrap around and take up multiple rows.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized I can accomplish what I am attempting to do by using panelGrid and outputfield instead of dataTable.